# Convert 3 columns to Short Datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o0dR.png)i have a `table` called "`Users`" which has various columns and 3 of them are `varchar` (Yearbirth, Monthbirth, Daybirth) with values. I want to convert complete `date` with the `datetime` format,

how can I do that? i thought of doing a `concat` first , after that what would be the next step?

Comment: can you please post the how the column data looks like and how you need to convert ...some sample data

Comment: Its something like this

Yearbirth |  Monthbirth  |  Datbirth
1979       |      5              |       1
1978       |       10            |       5
1975       |       1              |       1

Comment: fine but how you need output sample data

Comment: tag either sql-server or mysql. which database you are working? Also post pls the screenshot of the table data

Comment: I need the output in date time format like "1/5/1979"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table (yearbirth int,monthbirth int,Datebirth int)
insert into @t (yearbirth,monthbirth,Datebirth) values (1979 ,5,1)

select CONCAT(Datebirth,'/',monthbirth,'/',yearbirth) from @t
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think CONCAT function is supported in MS-SQL. This might work

```
select cast (('Column_Year' + '/' + 'Column_Month' + '/' + 'Column_Date') as datetime) from Table_name
```

Comment: It doesnt work... #1584 - Incorrect parameters in the call to stored function 'cast'

Comment: Would be helpful if you can share screenshot of the data and error

Comment: Im not allowed to share the screenshot because i dont have sufficient reputation

Comment: Would you be able to upload the screenshot on a third party site and share the link here?